# python capture and store curl command process id

Tags: python

i have a python script which uses threading to run a process.
It starts three threads executing curl commands on a different server.
i am not using threading sub-processes or any python sub-processes (as my version of python does not support it ) and I want to kill these specific running curl processes on the different server.

I want to capture the process id at the time the curl command is executed, put it in a list and then use this list of PID's to kill if necessary.

What is the best way to do this ?

I have tried a few ways but nothing working ..

```
curl command & echo $!
```

will return the value to screen but i want to capture this.  I have tried to set as a variable, export it ..

If i try:

```
ret,output = remoteConnection.runCmdGetOutput(cmd)
```

it will return the output (which includes the pid) of one curl command (the first one), but not all 3 (i think this has to do with the threading) and the parent script continues.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: If these processes are not subprocesses (how is that even possible?) it's not possible to do what you are asking. Showing your code would perhaps help us understand the problem better.

Comment: The python script is thousands on lines long, so i will try and explain.  In summary python script A has a function B which when executed, starts 3 threads. downloadfromserverthread 1,2 and 3.  This downloadfromserverthread function for each thread runs a curl command on a different server.  I want to kill these curl commads

Comment: The parts of the code where the threads are created and/or the definition of `remoteConnection` could be good starting points. Without actual code, there is too much guesswork about which *precise* problem you are trying to solve. Try to create a [mcve].

Comment: If that's from [`executor`](https://executor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) then that's explicitly and very definitely a subprocess.